# The novel adjective in the expression 'novel coronavirus'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What the meaning of novel that describes the coronavirus?
Is it from:
1, new - a new virus.
or:
2. original - the strain that can bring new children that are not the original virus?

Comment: The word "**novel**" could never mean (or even *imply*) "can bring new children that are not the original virus", except insofar as the "parent" of a new / novel virus must have had that ability, which *might* be considered "heritable". But that sense might attach to the word "**innovative**", which I'm guessing is etymologically cognate.

Comment: Lucky for us, latest thinking seems to be that Covid-19 is relatively ***un-** innovative* (doesn't mutate as much as 'flu viruses, for example), so if we ***do*** manage to produce a vaccine, that might imply it'll provide long-term immunity

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - O.K. I read your answer. Is the meaning that s cognate - new kind of member in the family that has DNA different in a way that doesn't change is kind or hertiable -  The the "father" of corona family is the same

Comment: Yeah - a "novel" virus simply means a virus we haven't seen before. Note that (practically?) all viruses mutate a lot. It's just that relatively speaking Covid19 doesn't mutate as much as (many/most?) others.

Answer (score 1):

Though **"severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2 (SARS-CoV-2)”** is genetically related to the coronavirus responsible for the SARS outbreak of 2003, it's a new member in the corona family because the two viruses are different. Hence the name *"2019 **novel** coronavirus"* and the name of the disease is COVID-19. ["COVID" stands for *"coronavirus disease"*.]